# Set the Threshold value in the Output from the FCN

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, threshold

I've been trying to use FCN to segment medical images. In the Evaluation part, I need to transfer the output of the network into a binary matrix with a threshold.
I tried to use cv2.threshold
`pred_bin = cv2.threshold(pred,0.95,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`

pred is the Output of the FCN(probability), with the size [batch_size,240,240,1]
However, I got the error

> ```
> pred_bin = cv2.threshold(pred,0.95,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
> ```
>
> TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

So what should I do?

Comment: What is `pred`? Is the output of the graph (thus a `Tensor` object) or the output of the session execution (`pred = sess.run(tensor)`)? Because it should be the second case and should work. I guess you're using a `Tensor`

Comment: I think pred is a Tensor object. I got pred from the output of the network. So what should I do when pred is a Tensor?

Comment: Executing it whitin a session as I showed you above and the use the value in the threshold function. Something like `value = sess.run(pred)` & `pred_bin = cv2.threshold(value,0.95,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`.